# Can the off-topic close reasons be re-arranged?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

Now that there's a re-written shopping question close reason, the generic "not relevant to system administration" close reason has moved up.  Is it possible to move it back? i.e. so that it's just above the "this question belongs on another site?"  I think that's a better sequence for the close reasons and my muscle memory led me astray once tonight.

Answer (score 5):

<s>There's no UI provided to us</s> Moderators now have the capability to rearrange the close reasons. But we can't edit them; to change one, it has to be deactivated and a completely new one activated.

Personally I think that the *most frequently used* reasons should be listed near the top. And I have taken the opportunity, when installing a new close reason, to rearrange the existing ones, to that end.

I'd welcome hearing specific suggestions, but I do recommend taking care when closing a question; this really shouldn't be *so* automatic that there's muscle memory involved.

Comment: Could you delete and then re-create the generic "not relevant to professional system admin" reason?  Or maybe an SE staff member reading this could re-arrange them...

Comment: Then someone else will come along and complain about them being rearranged _again_... You just can't win.

Comment: That would just be whining, whereas *my* complaint is, of course, totally reasonable and valid.

Comment: Reading the question and deciding which of the close reasons is appropriate shouldn't be too automated. But once you have decided which of the close reasons is appropriate, the few clicks to chose it should be fairly automatic (unless the close reason you intended to use no longer exists).